# Create more than one artboard when document is already saved?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I'm already working with an artboard, but i need two more, how can I add additional artboards to my document in Illustrator?

Answer (score 16):

New artboards can be added by either of the two:

1. Pick the Artboard Tool and click-drag it in the canvas area of the Illustrator document.
2. Pick the Artboard Tool, click on the <kbd>New Artboard</kbd> in the Control Panel, select the desired size from the list of Artboard Presets in the Control Panel and click in the desired area of the canvas to add a new Artboard.

**You will get determined help in Adobe community - as below..**

**The Artboards panel allows you to perform various artboard operations such as:**

- Add, reorder, rearrange, and delete artboards
- Reorder and renumber artboards
- Select and navigate through multiple artboards
- Specify artboard options such as presets, Artboard size, and relative
  artboard position.

**To access the Artboards panel, click `Window > Artboards`.**

---

***To add artboards:***

1. Click <kbd>New Artboard</kbd> at the bottom of the Artboards panel, OR
2. Select the New Artboard option from the Artboards panel menu (flyout
   menu) of the Artboards panel.

***To delete artboards:***

1. Select the artboard to delete. To delete multiple artboards, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the artboards listed in the Artboards panel.
2. Click the Delete Artboard icon at the bottom of the Artboards panel or select the Delete option from the Artboards panel menu (flyout menu). To delete multiple non-contiguous artboards, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>(Mac OS) and click the artboards from the Artboards panel.

To rearrange artboards in the Artboards panel, select the Rearrange Artboards option from the Artboards panel menu (flyout menu). Notice, however, that rearranging the artboards does not change the order the artboards.

***To duplicate artboards:***

1. Select the artboard that you want to duplicate. You can also
   duplicate artboards by dragging one or more artboards on to the new
   artboard button in Artboards panel.
2. From the Artboards panel menu, select Duplicate.

If you want to reset the artboard options, such as presets, artboard position, and display. Select Artboards Options from the Artboards panel menu (flyout menu).

Comment: Nidha, you've provided great information, but it may be of more help if you broke down the answer and summarized it as opposed to copy/pasting it. Also, I've edited it to change the answers to not be placed in code formatting which was unreadable and horizontally scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Adam for suggestion. I will take care of this in future..

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to add new artboards in Illustrator. The Artboard tool will help you to do that. Select it form the toolbar menu or pres Shift+O. The actual artboard will be highlighted and all you have to do in order to add a new one is to simple draw a rectangular shape and the new artboard will be automatically added.